# How do you get realtime database rules back after you hit firebase deploy in terminal?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I made a function and in terminal hit firebase deploy, instead of firebase deploy -- only functions. Now it has reset the database rules. How do I get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to revert to the previous rules of your Realtime Database once you've overwritten them.

While this feature was added to the Firestore console a while ago, it wasn't added to the Realtime Database. You might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it to be added, but for now you'll have to reconstruct the rules yourself.

Comment: can't they be found in some old file from when the initialization was done?

Comment: fair point. My bad, I wasn't on SO for a few days. I did rewrite all the rules.